# A plugin is causing a caching issue

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a website which was created in 2013. We installed a plugin for woocommerce which cleans-up inside woocommerce, like custom checkout pages. It basically handles lots of inside pages of my store.

We recently kept updating our other plugins and moved to php 7 as well. The issue is the plugin which was made for us and the people who made it, went out of business.

Most recently the plugin is causing so many issues, like my dynamic content after clients log in are not working sometimes. Catching causes issues and sometimes website gives server issues and other issues.

After doing lots of research we have found that the plugin which was handling woocommerce is the culprit. Is there any way you guys can look at the code of this plugin and help me?

PS: the company who made this plugin, went out of business and can not help me anymore.

Here is the download link to full plugin please.

https://files.fm/u/jtjef3y3

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and took a look at your plugin. The plugin is doing alot - so disabling would likely cause many issues. I will outline the various functions and what they are doing - hopefully that can help you identify which function may be causing issues, and you could just comment out that piece. Although I am not seeing anything there specific to caching or dynamic content in this plugin.

- **smn_woo_cleanup_check_fields**: removing and rearranging fields from the checkout form
- **smn_woo_cleanup_order_notes**: removed the order notes field from checkout form
- **smn_woo_cleanup_scripts**: adds some css and javascript to be loaded on woo pages
- **printIEMeta**: adds X-UA-Compatible meta tag
- **smn_woo_cleanup_wpheader**: removed various non-woo related meta tags from the
- **smn_woo_cleanup_order_redirect**: redirect to the custom Upsell path rather than the generic transaction results page
- **smn_woo_cleanup_locate_template**: includes a seperate template for checkout/product list
- **smn_woo_cleanup_logout_link**: adds my account link
- **smn_woo_cleanup_per_product_upsell_input**: adds additional product meta fields for some upsell thing
- **smn_woocommerce_cleanup_process_product**: sanitizes inputs for above
- **smn_woocommerce_cleanup_datalayer_initial_push**: adds some extra tracking info for google tag manager and infusionsoft
- **smn_clean_post_content**: removed all inline styles from post content
- **is_blog_page**: checks if is blog page
- **smn_woo_cleanup_remove_related_products**: returns no related products every time
- **smn_login_redirect**: redirects users after login